# Entity Framework Code First Revert Database to empty

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've tried using Entity Framework Code First and set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to true so that when I change the model classes the database would automatically update.

Then I have a table, where I added length to one field. Example
`Employee.Firstname(50)` -> `Employee.Firstname(100)`. The updated was successful.

But I have entered wrong data so I want to reset the database so I execute:

```
update-database -targetmigration:"0" -force -verbose
```

But I got the ff error:
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.`

Currently, my solution is to delete all the tables in the database manually as well as delete all the records in `__MigrationHistory`, then reinstall the `EntityFramework.Migrations` via NuGet.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that there is a new EntityFramework.Migrations (version 0.8.0.0.0) available in NuGet, and this version solves my issue.

Comment: If you've solved the problem yourself, please supply that as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by updating to EntityFramework.Migrations version 0.8.0.0.0.